# What are these strange environment variables?

Tags: windows, winapi, environment-variables

I use `GetEnvironmentString()` to get the program's environment variables.

Every program has such result in the first:

```
=::=::\
```

I don't know what does it mean?

Here is the code :

```
LPWCH lpEnvString=GetEnvironmentStringsW();
 LPWSTR lpszVariable=(LPWSTR)lpEnvString;
 while (*lpszVariable)
 {
     wprintf(L"%s\n",lpszVariable);
     lpszVariable+=wcslen(lpszVariable)+1;
 }
 FreeEnvironmentStringsW(lpEnvString);
```

Also if we start listing such variables we would see stuff like:

```
=::=::\
=C:=C:\Users\username\value
=ExitCode=00000001
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
APPDATA=C:\Users\artik\AppData\Roaming
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
...
```

On the other hand, `getenv("=ExitCode")` or `getenv("=C:")` returns NULL.

Can you provide a proper documentation of this "feature",
for example `getenv()` ignores such strings and how such values should be treated?

Comment: @Nick All you need to do is call `GetEnvironmentStrings()`

Comment: I guess I was wanting to check what he was doing with the return value in order to get the string provided. Also - you're assuming I have a windows PC :)

Comment: [What are these strange =C: environment variables?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/05/06/10008132.aspx)

Comment: @RaymondChen: You should post this as an answer.

Comment: @TimPietzcker It's not an answer. It's a link to an answer. If the OP thinks it's an answer, they can answer their own question and accept it.

Comment: It's half an answer.  I knew that the environment variable `=X:` is the current directory for `X:`, but what is `=::`?

Comment: @RaymondChen what exactly do you mean by "it's a bug"?  That's what the output should look like.  A quick google search of getEnvironmentStrings() turned up this example with the same output:  http://spottedtiger.tripod.com/D_Language/D_Win32_GetEnvironmentStrings.html

Comment: It's a bug in Windows that it created the bogus environment variable in the first place.

Comment: [What are these strange =C: environment variables?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100506-00/?p=14133) (Microsoft just loves breaking hyperlinks...)

Comment: I found myself here because these environment variables somehow snuck into and broke by docker 4.24.2 environment on Windows: `Error response from daemon: invalid environment variable: =::=::\` and therefore my Docker Python interpreter on Pycharm. Still looking for a fix.

Comment: Apparently Jetbrains has a docker-compose environment override which must have copied these weird Windows environment variables at some point. I looked at the exact command that was running in the terminal and saw ```C:\Users\<MyUsername>\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PyCharm2021.2\tmp\docker-compose.override.520.yml``` and inside that it I found it was trying to set ```'=::': "::\\"```

Comment: In a Jetbrains IDE Run Config for Docker next to Environment variables, there is a button that looks like a piece of paper. Click it and uncheck 'include system variables'.

Answer (score 14):

They are leftovers from cmd.exe emulating ms-dos directory handling, they basically have little use, and are more archaic than anything. Essentially, it keeps track of a per drive current directory, and is kept as an environment variable to pass to other processes with ease.

Comment: The question is more for documentation of how for example getenv should handle them etc. Pointers to docs required.

Comment: @Artyom, I think the takeaway is that anything starting with `=` is private to the shell and intentionally undocumented, and should be ignored.

Comment: @MarkRansom the problem is that these strings appear in the GetEnvironmentStrings list and such a behavior seems to be undocumented on unclear about how to handle them

Comment: @Artyom, is ignoring them not a sufficient way of handling them? The entire philosophy of environment strings is that you use the ones you care about, and ignore the rest.