# GetEnvironmentStrings and stange values "=::=::\"

Tags: c, winapi, environment-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are these strange environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431689/what-are-these-strange-environment-variables)

I'm trying to use GetEnvironmentStrings Win32API function to get environment variables
and I receive some very strange key=value pairs (example enclosed with []):

```
[=::=::\]
[=C:=C:\Users\username\value]
[=ExitCode=00000001]
[ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData]
[APPDATA=C:\Users\artik\AppData\Roaming]
[CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files]
[CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files]
[CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files]
...
```

Obviously it does not seems to be a proper value for environment
string as described there http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Questions:

- What is the expected behavior?
- If there are "special variables like `=ExitCode` Why,
  for example `getenv()` does not show them (`getenv("=ExitCode")` returns NULL)
- Can anybody provide pointers to documentation/specifications of this stuff.

Comment: Are you sure you are not reading beyond the returned array size?

Comment: Thought I had seen this before; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431689/what-are-these-strange-environment-variables unfortunately no direct answer as to what %::% is

Comment: @RedX yes, I'm sure, in fact I had seen some notes about such a strange strings but had not found a reason for that or documentation...

Comment: It's an [internal implementation detail](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/05/06/10008132.aspx) of the command prompt. See the duplicate question for a bit more discussion.

Comment: Before you vote for closing, see that the "exact duplicate" has no answer and it is not exact duplicate...

Comment: This was very stupid to close the question: (a) it is not full duplicate (b) the duplicate has no answer!!!