# List all environment variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab, environment-variables

How does one get a list of all defined environment variables in Matlab? I'm aware of `getenv` but you have to provide a name, and `doc getenv` offers no help in how to use it to retrieve items in any other way. I can't find any other relevant information online. Is this even possible?

I'm interested in a platform-independent answer (or at least Windows and Linux).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is a function that implements two ways to retrieve all environment variables (both methods are cross-platform):

1. using Java capabilities in MATLAB
2. using system-specific commands (as [@sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20006391/97160) suggested)

NOTE: As @Nzbuu explained in the comments, using Java's `System.getenv()` has a limitation in that it returns environment variables captured at the moment the MATLAB process starts. This means that any later changes made with `setenv` in the current session will not be reflected in the output of the Java method. The system-based method does not suffer from this.

#### getenvall.m

```
function [keys,vals] = getenvall(method)
    if nargin < 1, method = 'system'; end
    method = validatestring(method, {'java', 'system'});

    switch method
        case 'java'
            map = java.lang.System.getenv();  % returns a Java map
            keys = cell(map.keySet.toArray());
            vals = cell(map.values.toArray());
        case 'system'
            if ispc()
                %cmd = 'set "';  %HACK for hidden variables
                cmd = 'set';
            else
                cmd = 'env';
            end
            [~,out] = system(cmd);
            vars = regexp(strtrim(out), '^(.*)=(.*)$', ...
                'tokens', 'lineanchors', 'dotexceptnewline');
            vars = vertcat(vars{:});
            keys = vars(:,1);
            vals = vars(:,2);
    end

    % Windows environment variables are case-insensitive
    if ispc()
        keys = upper(keys);
    end

    % sort alphabetically
    [keys,ord] = sort(keys);
    vals = vals(ord);
end
```

Example:

```
% retrieve all environment variables and print them
[keys,vals] = getenvall();
cellfun(@(k,v) fprintf('%s=%s\n',k,v), keys, vals);

% for convenience, we can build a MATLAB map or a table
m = containers.Map(keys, vals);
t = table(keys, vals);

% access some variable by name
disp(m('OS'))   % similar to getenv('OS')
```

Comment: +1 Like this one - I'd use this version to be honest. Surely should also be much faster - in case one needs to get them more than one time.

Comment: Yeah, this version is cleaner and presumably more platform-independent. I always forget about Java tricks in Matlab!

Comment: The Java one actually gives different results that don't match `getenv` and `setenv`. See https://gist.github.com/Nzbuu/7c657a3b22f535eb41dc55e12e4440da.

Comment: @Nzbuu two things to note: 1) `System.getenv` returns the environment variables at the time MATLAB process was launched (JVM is embedded in MATLAB), this explains why it is not picking up change from `setenv`. This is different from `system` which spawns new processes 2) the `cmd.exe` shell has some private variables that are not displayed by default (leftover from MS-DOS days). One trick is to change the command executed to `cmd = 'set "';` to enumerate them, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/10431689/97160, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/05/06/10008132.aspx for more info.

Comment: that last hack (set + space + doublequote) is actually a bug that became a feature :) https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140425-00/?p=1143/

Comment: @Amro, I figured that it was the environment variables at the time MATLAB starts. However, that does make it significantly less useful because it does not match with `getenv` and `setenv`. Hence, I think that the "correct" answer should be the `system` based one.

Comment: I think that it's worth highlighting this limitation in the answer, at least.

Comment: @Nzbuu: done. I also combined both methods into a helper function (`system` based-one being the default)

Answer (score 10):

You could use

```
system('env')
```

on linux/mac, and

```
system('set') % hope I remember correctly, no windows at hand
```

In both cases you'd have to parse the output though, as it comes in the format `variable=<variable-value>`.

Comment: I fixed the quotes and those work as expected. Honestly, having the variables listed with their values is probably a good thing, so this works fairly well. I'm still curious if there's a truly platform-independent way, but since environment variables are fairly platform-dependent, this might be as good as it gets.

Comment: You can also use `!env` in the MATLAB console window then. Just as additional hint.