# What is the meaning of environment variable !::=::\

Tags: bash, cygwin, environment-variables

I have found out my environment variables a strange line:

```
$ env
...
!::=::\
...
```

When I start a shell or run bash script, it is sometimes present, sometimes not. And when it is absent my bash calls to subshells $(...) require 3 escape backslashes instead of each 1.

Any idea what it is and how to set it?

Comment: what OS and version? Also bash/zsh/etc? And version? AND do you work primarily inside of a Ruby or Python (or other) programming environment? Interesting. Good luck.

Comment: it's a bash only script, run under windows7 with cygwin.

Comment: Maybe you could try grepping for that in your filesystem.  Try some variations on `grep -r '!::=::\\' /`.  Not sure how you'd need to change it up for cygwin, though.

Comment: At output of "env", what appears in line before and after this one?

Comment: I see that env var in my git-bash environments also. Can you give an example of the sub-shell command issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's Cygwin's representation of one of the [special environment variables](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/05/06/10008132.aspx) created by the Windows command processor (cmd.exe) in order to track a separate current directory for each drive the same way MS-DOS did. You should also see entries like `!C:=C:\Users\Ross Ridge` in the output of env.  The Windows command processor creates them in the form `=X:=X:\Path`, but Cygwin changes the initial `=` to a `!` in order to make it a legal Unix environment entry.

So the reason why you see `!::=::\` in the Cygwin environment is because `=::=::\` was in the Windows environment that Cygwin inherited. I'm not sure why there was an `=::=::\` entry in the Windows environment, `:` is not a legal drive letter, but [Raymond Chen says it's a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431689/what-are-these-strange-environment-variables#comment14220830_10431689). It exists in the Windows environment on my computer even when I use Win-R to start Cygwin bash directly without using cmd.exe, so it's not clear what's actually setting it.

Comment: Nicely found and good reference links. This doesn't answer the ancillary question about the escaping difference (but I'm skeptical about that issue to begin with).